# Replace NAs with a random number in column R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two columns, clientid and clientname, some clients don't have an id and I need to assign a non-duplicated random id if the client name is the same. I thought I had it with this:

`df1 <- df %>% dplyr::group_by(clientname) %>% dplyr::mutate(clientid = ifelse(is.na(clientid), sample(1:10000), clientid))`

but I am still getting duplicates in the random number sample, even though the client names are very different.

```
clientname <- c("Mr A", "Mr B", "Mr B", "Mr C", "Mr D")
clientid <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1)

df <- data.frame(clientname,clientid)
df
  clientname clientid
1       Mr A       NA
2       Mr B       NA
3       Mr B       NA
4       Mr C       NA
5       Mr D        1

df1 <- df %>% dplyr::group_by(clientname) %>% dplyr::mutate(clientid = ifelse(is.na(clientid), sample(1:10000), clientid))
df1
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   clientname [4]
  clientname clientid
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 Mr A            948
2 Mr B           4004
3 Mr B           7888
4 Mr C           4668
5 Mr D              1
```

I want it to look like this in the end where "Mr B" has the same clientid but its different to the other clientnames

```
> df1
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   clientname [4]
  clientname clientid
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 Mr A            948
2 Mr B           4004
3 Mr B           4004
4 Mr C           4668
5 Mr D              1
```

Answer (score 2):

To make sure you're not using an existing ID, could add to the max existing ID

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

clientname <- c("Mr A", "Mr B", "Mr B", "Mr C", "Mr D")
clientid <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1)

df <- data.frame(clientname,clientid)

df %>% 
  mutate(temp_id = max(clientid, na.rm = T) + as.numeric(as.factor(clientname)),
         clientid = coalesce(clientid, temp_id),
         temp_id = NULL)
#>   clientname clientid
#> 1       Mr A        2
#> 2       Mr B        3
#> 3       Mr B        3
#> 4       Mr C        4
#> 5       Mr D        1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Although, I'm assuming "random" isn't actually requirement and what's meant is just "the value isn't important"

Comment: Yes that is right, the value isn't important as long as its not the same as another :)

Comment: In my realdata I am getting -Inf as the outcome for the NA clientid's. Running it with my real clientid the maximum number is 204023572. Changing the clientname is a numeric gives me a max of 57510 so I thought it couldn't compute a number that large. I added in /1000 after `as.numeric(as.factor(ClientName))/1000` but I getting this warning : Problem while computing `temp_id = max(clientid, na.rm = T) + ...`.
i no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance of duplicate random numbers being assigned in my original answer (thanks Ritchie Sacramento for pointing out my oversight!). See the edited answer below for a better solution.

---

### Original answer:

The `if_else()` dplyr function helps explain/understand the problem; basically, when you use `sample(1:1000)` you are generating a vector with 1000 random numbers. When you use `ifelse()`, these numbers are used to 'fill' the NAs one-by-one and the rest of the numbers are discarded. The `if_else()` function throws a warning in this scenario ('you need the right number of random numbers'), so if you specify 'how many' random numbers you want to select from `1:1000` (i.e. 1 per clientname), you get the desired outcome, e.g.

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

clientname <- c("Mr A", "Mr B", "Mr B", "Mr C", "Mr D")
clientid <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1)

df <- data.frame(clientname,clientid)
df
#>   clientname clientid
#> 1       Mr A       NA
#> 2       Mr B       NA
#> 3       Mr B       NA
#> 4       Mr C       NA
#> 5       Mr D        1

df %>%
  group_by(clientname) %>%
  mutate(clientid = if_else(is.na(clientid), sample(1:1000), clientid))
#> Error in `mutate()`:
#> ℹ In argument: `clientid = if_else(is.na(clientid), sample(1:1000),
#>   clientid)`.
#> ℹ In group 1: `clientname = "Mr A"`.
#> Caused by error in `if_else()`:
#> ! `true` must have size 1, not size 1000.
#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. ├─df %>% group_by(clientname) %>% ...
#>   2. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
#>   3. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
#>   4. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
#>   5. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>   6. │   └─dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
#>   7. │     └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
#>   8. │       └─dplyr (local) eval()
#>   9. └─dplyr::if_else(is.na(clientid), sample(1:1000), clientid)
#>  10.   └─dplyr:::vec_case_when(...)
#>  11.     └─vctrs::vec_assert(value, size = size, arg = value_arg, call = call)
#>  12.       └─vctrs:::stop_assert_size(x_size, size, arg, call = call)
#>  13.         └─vctrs:::stop_assert(...)
#>  14.           └─vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
#>  15.             └─rlang::abort(message, class = c(class, "vctrs_error"), ..., call = call)

df %>%
  group_by(clientname) %>%
  mutate(clientid = if_else(is.na(clientid), sample(1:1000, 1), clientid))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#> # Groups:   clientname [4]
#>   clientname clientid
#>   <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 Mr A            901
#> 2 Mr B            113
#> 3 Mr B            113
#> 4 Mr C             88
#> 5 Mr D              1

# If you change sample(1:1000) to sample(1:1000, 1) you can use the generic ifelse():
df %>%
  group_by(clientname) %>%
  mutate(clientid = ifelse(is.na(clientid), sample(1:1000, 1), clientid))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#> # Groups:   clientname [4]
#>   clientname clientid
#>   <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 Mr A            555
#> 2 Mr B            374
#> 3 Mr B            374
#> 4 Mr C            979
#> 5 Mr D              1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

More details on the difference between `if_else()` and `ifelse()`: https://medium.com/@statisticswithoutborders/r-function-of-the-week-ifelse-vs-if-else-bed37f474fca

---

### Edit 1:

Using the methods above there is a chance you will end up with the same clientid being allocated to two different clientnames (very bad). To avoid that, one potential option is:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(vctrs, warn = FALSE)

clientname <- c("Mr A", "Mr B", "Mr B", "Mr C", "Mr D")
clientid <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1)

df <- data.frame(clientname,clientid)
# change '+ 5' to '+ 1000' or however many you need
random_numbers <- sample(max(df$clientid, na.rm = TRUE): max(df$clientid, na.rm = TRUE) + 5)
available_numbers <- random_numbers[!random_numbers %in% df$clientid]
available_numbers
#> [1] 3 6 4 5 2
# Fill the NAs 'sequentially', regardless of group
df$clientid[is.na(df$clientid)] <- available_numbers
#> Warning in df$clientid[is.na(df$clientid)] <- available_numbers: number of
#> items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
df
#>   clientname clientid
#> 1       Mr A        3
#> 2       Mr B        6
#> 3       Mr B        4
#> 4       Mr C        5
#> 5       Mr D        1

# Then, fill 'down' the clientid from the first clientname in each group
df %>%
  group_by(clientname) %>%
  mutate(groupid = cumsum(!is.na(clientname))) %>%
  mutate(clientid = ifelse(groupid >= 2, NA, clientid)) %>%
  mutate(clientid = vec_fill_missing(clientid, direction = "down")) %>%
  select(-groupid)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#> # Groups:   clientname [4]
#>   clientname clientid
#>   <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 Mr A              3
#> 2 Mr B              6
#> 3 Mr B              6
#> 4 Mr C              5
#> 5 Mr D              1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This is a complicated answer to a simple question, but it ensures (I believe) that the 'random' numbers are assigned as required.

Comment: OP can clarify but this approach leaves open the possibility that the randomly generated IDs will match existing IDs (i.e. the data already contains ID 1 but OP is sampling 1:10000), and also as the sampling is a group operation, the same ID could be generated for multiple groups.

Comment: That's a significant caveat! Thanks for pointing that out Ritchie Sacramento - I'll edit my answer. IceCreamToucan's answer avoids this problem (+1), so I'll come up with a different way to avoid that issue